# Inserting data in sql server using jquery and ajax ? Throwing error?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Inserting data in sql server using jquery and ajax. But i am getting error like 
[object xmlhttprequest]. I am using asp.net for inserting the data using ajax and jquery
below is my code:

```
          <script type ="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClose').click(function () {
            var name = $('#txtsname').val();
            var tot = $('#txttotal').val();               
            $.ajax({
                url: 'JqueryAjax.aspx/InsertData',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                                                                 
                data: "{'stname':'" + name +"','totalmarks':'" + tot + "'}",
                success: function (data) {

                    alert('Inserted Susccessfully');
                },

                error: function (xhr, status, error,data) {
                    alert(xhr);

                    alert('Not inserted');
                },


            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Paste the error trace.

Comment: i not understand what you mean by error trace. I got error like [object xmlhttprequest] Mr. tailorBird

Comment: I mean some specific error would be there in the console or wherever. How come the `[object xmlhttprequest]` be an error?

Comment: at error: function i am getting the same

Comment: error: function (xhr, status, error,data)  for error undefine, for data: undefine i am getting these errors